# Get video views for Instagram posts error in Graph Api

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I am using the graph api explorer to create a query to get insights data about my Instagram page. It looks like this and it works fine. Some posts are photos some are videos.

```
IG id/media?fields=timestamp,caption,permalink,media_type,like_count,comments_count,insights.metric(reach,impressions,saved,engagement)
```

When i add the video_views metric though i get an error

> "message": "(#100) Can not show video views count for non video media"

Anyone know what am i doing wrong? I just want to get the video views if the post is a video.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably too late, but if you call 'video_views' on an IMAGE media, it will give you this error.
You must handle the IMAGE and VIDEO media separately (i mean with separate fields)

Something like : (pseudo code)

```
if(post_type == 'VIDEO'):
    fields for video ...
else:
    fields for image ...
```